# Representation theory of $U(2)$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Where can I find a complete description of all irreducible representation of $U(2)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See e.g. these [lecture notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/RepThry.pdf) by Constantin Teleman, section 22.

Comment: Excellent lecture notes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For a book reference, see Chapter II. Section 5 of Chapter II of  "Representations of Compact Lie Groups" by Brocker and Dieck.